# connect two output with one kcd2 button

Tags: power, source

i have a power source that gives 24v output from 3 outs.

I need to connect two outs to 1 kcd2 button.

Is this possible?

I need this because i have to power 2 boards from two outputs so that i dont overcharge the power source.

is this possible?

Something like:

```
             - out 1 \             / board 1
Power source           kcd2 button
             - out 2 /             \ board 2
```

I could just put the button in the power in of the power source but that way i couldnt use the  3 out with the out 1 and 2 off

Comment: all three outputs are probably connected together internally, so they are really only one output ... please provide a link to the power supply datasheet

Comment: its this one https://pt.banggood.com/Creality-3D-24V-or-15A-Universal-Regulated-Switching-Mode-LED-Power-Supply-For-Ender-3-3D-Printer-p-1335224.html?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_organic&gmcCountry=PT&utm_content=minha&utm_campaign=minha-ptg-pt-pc&currency=EUR&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgcs&utm_content=dcr&utm_campaign=dcr-pmax-ptg-dc-1127&ad_id=&gclid=Cj0KCQiAqvaNBhDLARIsAH1Pq50qggE6JVUKCVwi8IszIyrx-PF6732yy8QVwTzCI3LP2bhY6eR_DEAaAt5dEALw_wcB. thanks

Comment: that's not the datasheet ... anyway, there is probanly only one output ... it just happens to have three screws for connecting wires ... check with an ohmmeter ... it probably makes no real difference how many wires you connect to the power supply ... one wire to one switch, then from switch to two boards would be the simplest

Comment: thanks , this is the graph im following, they advise on plug the two separatelly, do you think it would be ok to do it from the same out?https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/a83a7122-b608-46c0-b1a1-fafe9f535875.4bfcf0e773bf8c7bbd694e2be7020ad8.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=ffffff